# Error connecting Zoho books API with Bubble.io

Tags: zohobooks, bubble.io

I am facing authentication error while connecting Zoho books API with Bubble.io.
Here is my setup: https://i.stack.imgur.com/8lKQs.jpg
Error message: https://i.stack.imgur.com/93pKO.jpg

Will appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check out this guide from a user that was able to integrate Zoho and bubble.io: https://forum.bubble.io/t/api-setup-with-zoho-creator/135335/2

Also, looking at the your configuration you should at least include: `aaaserver.profile.READ` in the "Scope" field.

I hope this is helpful!

Comment: I followed that post but it's not working. Looks like it's bubble's internal error.